# Android меню

Tags: android, java

Необходимо сделать по нажатию на кнопку открытие что-то вроде контекстного меню таким образом, что бы оно открылось не в центре экрана, а рядом с этой кнопкой. По аналогии как в Play Маркет при нажатии на элементе трех точек, открывающих контекстное меню.
[image]

Что для этого нужно использовать?

Comment: Я помню в старой книге по Андроид была информация по созданию контекстного меню для View на экране. Поищите.

Comment: @Lucky_spirit Контекстное меню открывается в центре экрана.А мне нужно именно с привязкой к кнопке

Comment: Ну, так установите координаты для контекстного меню. Или Gravity по отношению к родителю.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте класс [PopupMenu](http://android-er.blogspot.ru/2012/03/example-of-using-popupmenu.html), и при создании укажите нужную кнопку как анкер.

Comment: API Level 11

Comment: PopupMenu есть в гугловских билиотеках поддержки aka support libraries. Можно еще сделать вот так http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/